# Reusable Vue JS search filter with grid layout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So after about 2-3 weeks of reading, trying simple examples, and taking baby steps in VueJs, attempting a more complex use-case and I'm stuck.

Created a basic search method to filter data by title, and return the results iteratively in a 3-column grid layout.

Now I need to make this something reusable.

1. Have multiple sections (like section2, section3, ...) with corresponding content data (contents2, contents3, ...) each responding to the filtering. e.g if I had Section 2 with titles of songs instead of Evernote and Pinterest, would still work the same way and lay out content in 3 columns.
2. Given that the filtering mechanism is essentially the same for every section, wanted to use it as a computed property instead of method (+ performance gain), but not sure how I can identify content for each section (e.g. content3 for section3), and return the filtered content in a 3-column grid without affecting other sections.

Of course, the 'brute force' way would be to write one filtering method for every content array. In reality though, I'm just a VueJs noob who knows that (2) is possible and can't code it up.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Search</h2>
  <div><input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Search" /></div>

  <section id="section1">
    <div class="row" v-for="i in rowCount" :key="i.id">
      <div v-for="content in filtered1(i)" :key="content.id" class="one-third">
        <img :src="content.image" class="center-block" />
        <h3>{{content.title}}</h3>
        <p class="m-t-content tablet">{{content.description}}</p>
        <p class="m-t-content mobile-center tablet"><a :href="content.url">Read more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section2">
  </section>  
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      searchString: '',
      itemsPerRow: 3,
      contents1: [
        {
          'title': 'Android',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/android-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Pinterest',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Consectetur adipiscing elit.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/pinterest-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Behance',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Pellentesque pulvinar nisi.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/behance-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Evernote',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Id tincidunt orci elementum.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/evernote-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Github',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/github-icon.png'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rowCount: function () {
      return Math.ceil(this.contents1.length / this.itemsPerRow)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filtered1: function (index) {
      var contentsArray = this.contents1
      var searchString = this.searchString

      if (!searchString) {
        return contentsArray.slice((index - 1) * this.itemsPerRow, index * this.itemsPerRow)
      }

      searchString = searchString.trim().toLowerCase()

      contentsArray = contentsArray.filter(function (item) {
        if (item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
          return item
        }
      })

      return contentsArray.slice((index - 1) * this.itemsPerRow, index * this.itemsPerRow)
    }
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.one-third {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 31.33%;  
}

.row {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Deep_end/e90nwa92/)

Comment: You can use `chunk` instead. Is not natively implemented in javascript, but you can use [this prototype](https://gist.github.com/webinista/11240585). Look: https://jsfiddle.net/8sgr4cuz/

Comment: @Phiter - thank you so much! This was helpful. Would still have to create a computed property for every content array though, right? as in .. filteredChunks1() for contents1[ ...], filteredChunks2() for contents2[ ...] and so on? (Although, one benefit is, I can control the items per row for every set.. )

Comment: Reusability in vue comes from components and directives. In your case, you should look into @Bert's answer. You should make a filtering component. Take a look into the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results

Comment: Bam! yes, that should do it. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple implementation of this would be to convert your Vue into a component, and expose the content for each rendered element to a slot so that the parent could set up custom content.

Here is an example of what I mean.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("filtered", {
 template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <div><input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Search" /></div>

    <section>
    <div class="row" v-for="i in rowCount" :key="i">
      <div v-for="content in filtered.slice(itemsPerRow * (i - 1), itemsPerRow * i)" :key="content[keyColumn]" class="one-third">
    <slot :content="content" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>  
  </div>
 `,
  props: ["contents", "itemsPerRow", "filterColumns", "keyColumn"],
  data(){
   return {
     searchString: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rowCount: function () {
      return Math.ceil(this.filtered.length / this.itemsPerRow)
    },
    filtered(){
      let results = this.contents
      if (!this.searchString)
        return results
        
      let searchString = this.searchString.toLowerCase()
        
      return results.filter(item => {
        for (let column of this.filterColumns)
          if (item[column].toLowerCase().includes(searchString))
            return true
        
        return false
      })
      
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      records:[
        {
          name: "Dark Side of the Moon",
          artist: "Pink Floyd"
        },
        {
          name: "Wish You Were Here",
          artist: "Pink Floyd",
        },
        {
          name: "The Joshua Tree",
          artist: "U2"
        }
      ],
      contents1: [
        {
          'title': 'Android',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/android-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Pinterest',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Consectetur adipiscing elit.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/pinterest-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Behance',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Pellentesque pulvinar nisi.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/behance-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Evernote',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Id tincidunt orci elementum.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/evernote-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Github',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/github-icon.png'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.one-third {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 31.33%;  
}

.row {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <filtered :contents="records" :items-per-row="2" :filter-columns="['name']" :key-column="'name'">
    <template slot-scope="{content}">
      <h4>{{content.name}}</h4>
    </template>
  </filtered>
  <filtered :contents="contents1" :items-per-row="3" :filter-columns="['title', 'description']" :key-column="'title'">
    <template slot-scope="{content}">
      <img :src="content.image" class="center-block" />
        <h3>{{content.title}}</h3>
        <p class="m-t-content tablet">{{content.description}}</p>
        <p class="m-t-content mobile-center tablet"><a :href="content.url">Read more</a></p>
    </template>
  </filtered>
</div>
```

Based on further discussion in the comments, you could use a common search string as follows:

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("filtered", {
  props: ["contents","itemsPerRow", "filterColumns", "keyColumn", "searchString"],
 template: `
    <section>
    <div class="row" v-for="i in rowCount" :key="i">
      <div v-for="content in filtered.slice(itemsPerRow * (i - 1), itemsPerRow * i)" :key="content[keyColumn]" class="one-third">
    <slot :content="content" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>  
 `,
  computed: {
    rowCount: function () {
      return Math.ceil(this.filtered.length / this.itemsPerRow)
    },
    filtered(){
      let results = this.contents
      if (!this.searchString)
        return results
        
      let searchString = this.searchString.toLowerCase()
        
      return results.filter(item => {
        for (let column of this.filterColumns)
          if (item[column].toLowerCase().includes(searchString))
            return true
        
        return false
      })
      
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      searchString: '',
      records:[
        {
          name: "Dark Side of the Moon",
          artist: "Pink Floyd"
        },
        {
          name: "Wish You Were Here",
          artist: "Pink Floyd",
        },
        {
          name: "The Joshua Tree",
          artist: "U2"
        }
      ],
      contents1: [
        {
          'title': 'Android',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/android-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Pinterest',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Consectetur adipiscing elit.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/pinterest-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Behance',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Pellentesque pulvinar nisi.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/behance-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Evernote',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Id tincidunt orci elementum.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/evernote-icon.png'
        },
        {
          'title': 'Github',
          'url': '/',
          'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
          'image': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/github-icon.png'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.one-third {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 31.33%;  
}

.row {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <div><input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Search" /></div>

  <filtered :contents="records" 
            :items-per-row="2" 
            :filter-columns="['name']" 
            :key-column="'name'"
            :search-string="searchString">
    <template slot-scope="{content}">
      <h4>{{content.name}}</h4>
    </template>
  </filtered>
  
  <filtered :contents="contents1" 
            :items-per-row="3" 
            :filter-columns="['title', 'description']" 
            :key-column="'title'"
            :search-string="searchString">
    <template slot-scope="{content}">
      <img :src="content.image" class="center-block" />
      <h3>{{content.title}}</h3>
      <p class="m-t-content tablet">{{content.description}}</p>
      <p class="m-t-content mobile-center tablet"><a :href="content.url">Read more</a></p>
    </template>
  </filtered>
</div>
```

Comment: Was just considering this path, when I saw your response. Thank you for your time and further optimizing even my existing approach ( includes over indexof :) and +1 for Pink Floyd.

Noticed couple of small things though: (1) Needed the search to be common for all data sets, so it can't be part of the component template (2) The itemsPerRow isn't iterating over the entire data set, instead going over only once.

As @Phiter suggested, guess I'd take the filtering into a component, and keep the iterations on the parent. Thank you for putting me on the right track :)

Comment: @DeepanjanDatta There was a bug in the code I posted originally, so your second issue I think is gone now. I'm not sure I understand your first point. The component takes an arbitrary set of data and allows you to specify the columns that will be searched. If all your data sets will have common properties on the other hand, then you don't necessarily need the slot and can just move that back into the component. Take a look at the revised code.

Comment: Just noticed it :) .. yes (2) is resolved. For (1) what I meant was, I needed just one search box to filter both data arrays simultaneously (records[ ], and _contents1[ ] in your example). e.g. If I search **er**, it should filter records[ ] to "Wish you w**er**e h**er**e" and contents1[ ] to "Pint**er**est" and "Ev**er**note"

Comment: @DeepanjanDatta Ah! I understand now. I'm headed out for the day but may swing back to this on the weekend.

Comment: @Deep Updated the answer to use a common search string across all the components.

Comment: my apologies, last night I had managed to pass 'searchString' as a prop, and get this to work. I should've updated here. Thank you so very much for the time. Definitely refined my understanding of custom components.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out!

A very simple and powerful grid based on VUEJS and this sample combined with ASP.NET MVC

https://github.com/Dariush-Tasdighi/LEARNING_VUE

Learn_1000 Action and view has filter!